# How to set Noindex to all wordpress pages in a catergory?

Tags: plugins, functions, noindex

I have a standard WordPress page category with tag_ID=92 which I want to noindex all posts in this category entirely. Is there a way to do it with actions/hooks in functions.php?

Comment: if you're using yoast already, why not just change the setting in yoast to do this for you for that category?

Comment: This only sets noindex to the category archive and not the pages inside the category.

Comment: then create a cpt for those pages and hide them in post type settings of yoast?

Answer (score 6):

As the previous code I posted didnt work for the OP, clutching at straws, we can try to obtain the same outcome using [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)
As the OP stated he was using YOAST, i'll wrap this function into the YOAST hook for robots.

```
add_filter('wpseo_robots', 'yoast_no_home_noindex', 999); 
function yoast_no_home_noindex($string= "") {
   $term_id = get_the_category( $post->ID );
      if($term_id[0]->term_id == 92) {
         $string= "noindex, nofollow";
      }
      return $string; 
}
```

Same again, just drop this into your themes functions file.

Comment: This time we have the meta tag on every page and post. It doesn't appear only on category 92, but on all pages of the site. :S

Comment: @File_Submit, me rushing, sorry.. should work fine now ..

Comment: I'm sorry to tell, but still not working :/

Comment: Then sorry to say, I'm stumped.. just a quick question, should have asked you long ago.. how are you adding the category to the page?

Comment: Like this: https://infinit.io/_/3mhuJst.png

Comment: No, I meant how are you getting the categories taxonomy onto your pages? Plugin, add_action?
Can you put this in your footer and see whats printed out? $term_id = get_the_category( $post->ID );
print_r($term_id);

Comment: It says Array ( ) - nothing else. but on Post (not Page) I've got a bunch of keys in the array

Comment: Then there lies the problem,it would seem the plugin or code you have used to add categories to pages, isnt woking correctly. You should get an output of the term associated with the page OR post

Comment: Look what I've found: codeshare.io/K7foR Look for page_category. Hope it helps for the array ()

Comment: The way I see that is this piece of code is registering a taxonomy to pages called ''taxonomy'=>'page_category'' and not category. hence the issue of why none of the core WP functions is working.

Shouldnt do this here as this is dragging on.. but I would simply use the following to register category tax to pages. then it will work.:
add_action('admin_init', 'reg_tax');
function reg_tax() {
      register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
      add_post_type_support('page', 'category');
}

Answer (score 3):

By noindex, I'm assuming you mean meta robots noindex, if so you could  manually do this by utilizing the [in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) function adding the following to your theme's header between the `<head></head>` tags, like so::

```
 <?php if(in_category( '92' ))
      echo "\t<meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />\r\n" ?>
```

Or, If you don't care to alter your theme directly, you could attach it to the [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action hook, place the following in your functions.php file usually located within your main theme or child themes folder.:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'noRobots');
function noRobots() {
    if(in_category( '92' )) echo "\t<meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />\r\n";
}
```

Both the above will return true if the current post is in the category with ID '92', can also be used with category name or slug, or an array of either.

Comment: Yes, I meant meta robots noindex. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work :( By the way, I am using Yoast plugin if that matters.

Comment: I've edited the answer, my bad, try in_category, instead of is_category

Comment: @Malisa you should really make it a fully useful code and answer.... use `wp_head`, explain where to place it and such.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, taken onboard what you say  and added further description and detail to answer

Comment: Hmm, weird - neither way appears to generate the mata tag. I've tried on fresh Twenty sixteen theme with no plugins.

Comment: @File_Submit That is strange, it works on my site.. Try changing the ID to the cat slug or name?

Comment: @File_Submit, Think out the box too, just a question, is category 92 a child of?

Comment: @Malisa - I found out that it works great for categories of Posts, but doesn't work for categories for Pages.

Comment: @File_Submit, can you try if (is_category('92') || in_category('92')).

Looking through the codex, it refrences in_category to posts and is_category to pages

Comment: I tried both is/in but no result. cat92 is parent category.

Comment: @File_Submit, The only other thing I can suggest is to try and get the term_id by using get_the_category. I'll post new answer below, specific to a yeost hook.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but answer can be updated. If you use WordPress version **5.7.0** or newer, you can use **filter** hook [`wp_robots`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_robots/).

```php
add_filter('wp_robots', 'mypluginRobotsFilter', 10, 1);
function mypluginRobotsFilter(array $robots)
{
    // use condition(s) check here to set "noindex"
    if (in_category('92')) {
        $robots['noindex'] = true;
    }
    return $robots;
}
```

This filter is used in many functions. See their documents as reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_robots_no_robots/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_robots_noindex/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_robots_noindex_search/

Answer (score -2):

in your html header add the following code :

```
<?php if (is_category('92')): ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: A little explanation of what the code does would be great. Remember that answers shoulud be useful for as many people as possible.

Comment: The code should add meta robots noindex to all posts inside the category 92.